# Moving annotations on Bar Chart with Negative Values Google Chart

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I am using google charts within an MVC project.

I am looking to implement a bar chart that has negative values.

I would like the annotations on the negative portion of the chart to be on the same side as the end of the bar (just like the positive, see image below, green box is where I would like annotations to be).

[image]

I cant seem to find any documentation on how this can be achieved.

Is it possible to move the annotation to the other side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are no standard config options that will move the annotations

but you can move them manually

however, the chart will actually move them back whenever activity occurs,
such as on bar hover
have to use a `MutationObserver`, or something, to keep them there

use chart methods --> `getChartLayoutInterface().getXLocation(value)`
to find the location

also, need to adjust the axis window to leave room for the labels

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {label: 'x', type: 'string'},
        {label: 'y0', type: 'number'},
      ],
      rows: [
        {c:[{v: 'Omega'}, {v: -0.95}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Large'}, {v: -0.92}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Medium'}, {v: 2.76}]},
        {c:[{v: 'Tiny'}, {v: 2.03}]}
      ]
    });

    var options = {
      annotations: {
        alwaysOutside: true,
        stem: {
          color: 'transparent'
        },
        textStyle: {
          color: '#000000'
        }
      },
      hAxis: {
        // leave room for annotation
        viewWindow: {
          min: data.getColumnRange(1).min - 1
        }
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'none'
      }
    };

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1, {
      calc: 'stringify',
      sourceColumn: 1,
      type: 'string',
      role: 'annotation'
    }]);

    var container = document.getElementById('chart');
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);

    // move annotations
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
      $.each($('text[text-anchor="start"]'), function (index, label) {
        var labelValue = parseFloat($(label).text());
        // only negative -- and -- not on tooltip
        if ((labelValue < 0) && ($(label).attr('font-weight') !== 'bold')) {
          var bounds = label.getBBox();
          var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
          $(label).attr('x', chartLayout.getXLocation(labelValue) - bounds.width - 8);
        }
      });
    });
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });

    chart.draw(view, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: WhiteHat Strikes Again! Thank you for your awesome input! Its greatly appreciated. You have no idea how much time and stress you have saved me! (and others!)

Comment: @WhiteHat can you give me any suggestion for what we do for coloum chart  i m applied same logic for coloum chart but it's not working.