# Is it possible to have alwaysOutside in google visualization depend on the value of the bar?

Tags: google-visualization

We have a horizontal google visualization chart, and there appears to be a bug where, if the value of the bar is zero, it will pop the label off to the left side of the axis, covering up the scale ticks, rather than pushing it to the right.  We noticed that, if we set alwaysOutside to true, the zero label works as expected, but we want the non-zero values to be inside the bars.  Is it possible to set custom values for alwaysOutside depending on the row, or does anyone else run into this bug?  What we're looking for is something like:

```
alwaysOutside: [true, false, false, false]
```

Comment: `alwaysOutside` is a boolean -- it will only accept `true` or `false` -- please share all the options used for the chart, could be a combination of things, seems to work fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zj587q99/) -- it is possible to move the annotations manually, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45243263/5090771)

Comment: This was really helpful, and got us a bit closer.  (We were setting too large of a font size, which firefox couldn't deal with.)  We are still seeing problems, however, when we add a fifth row.  Even in the JSFiddle example you provided, it works great with four rows, and works always in Chrome, but adding a fifth row in Firefox makes the 0 label disappear.

Comment: was able to reproduce in firefox [using this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zj587q99/1/), the label is there but it is white for some reason and below the axis -- it's trouble but labels below the axis can be identified using chart methods --> `chart.getChartLayoutInterface().getXLocation(0)` -- check if x location for zero is above x attribute on label, then move it, change the color, and add or clone a stem (ugh)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell you why, but setting the bar:groupWidth value to 75% somehow fixed the issue completely. The look is slightly different, but it's acceptable, and leaves out the hassle of having to modify the location of the label. Thanks for all of your help!