# Google Chart - negative/positive values annotation position

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I've got the following column chart and I'd like to position annotations for positive values above and for negative ones bellow columns. How to do that?

Additional question for values and annotation formatting - how to achieve the formatting of annotations (values above and bellow columns) like vAxis?

[image: my Google Chart]

```js
google.charts.load('current',{callback:drawChart,'packages':['corechart'],'language':'hr'});

function drawChart()
{
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date','Datum');
  data.addColumn('number','Vrijednost');
  data.addColumn('number','Pred. prema preth. 5 dana');
  data.addColumn('number','Pred. prema preth. 10 dana');
  data.addColumn('number','Relativna promjena');
  data.addRows([
  [new Date('2017-08-03'),12.10260,12.09797,12.148753333333,0.3199602122016],
  [new Date('2017-08-02'),12.06400,12.16005,12.176186666667,-0.69882870054079],
  [new Date('2017-08-01'),12.14890,12.12988,12.160606666667,0.3129386508133],
  [new Date('2017-07-31'),12.11100,12.13091,12.14988,-0.001651364026678],
  [new Date('2017-07-28'),12.11120,12.1175,12.116093333333,0.11821210392746],
  [new Date('2017-07-27'),12.09690,12.10942,12.079293333333,0.24113757271416],
  [new Date('2017-07-26'),12.06780,12.10184,12.040733333333,0],
  [new Date('2017-07-25'),12.06780,12.06525,11.992986666667,0.28753781205331],
  [new Date('2017-07-24'),12.03320,12.02595,11.95908,0.18983547592086],
  [new Date('2017-07-21'),12.01040,11.95357,11.932006666667,0.41468798073707],
  [new Date('2017-07-20'),11.96080,11.9183,11.9194,0.1951832460733],
  [new Date('2017-07-19'),11.93750,11.89151,11.914186666667,0.21154604904174],
  [new Date('2017-07-18'),11.91230,11.89439,11.937766666667,0.1235543302851],
  [new Date('2017-07-17'),11.89760,11.93811,11.967046666667,-0.36595680537295],
  [new Date('2017-07-14'),11.94130,11.95136,11.972373333333,0.068716427416171],
  [new Date('2017-07-13'),11.93310,11.96335,11.975713333333,-0.1848567987152],
  [new Date('2017-07-12'),11.95520,11.94968,11.96142,-0.070212979370754],
  [new Date('2017-07-11'),11.96360,11.95871,11.944226666667,0.19429834846403],
  [new Date('2017-07-10'),11.94040,11.9698,11.93224,0.099761076413629],
  [new Date('2017-07-07'),11.92850,11.96977,11.934313333333,-0.13478894228354],
  [new Date('2017-07-06'),11.94460,11.93426,11.931026666667,-0.10036297944233],
  [new Date('2017-07-05'),11.95660,11.86036,11.91198,0.66342251932174],
  [new Date('2017-07-04'),11.87780,11.86771,11.918093333333,0.048011724968622],
  [new Date('2017-07-03'),11.87210,11.88418,11.919446666667,-0.078273604120727],
  [new Date('2017-06-30'),11.88140,11.92094,11.907506666667,-0.076531684958581]
  ]);

  var ColumnOpt = {
    height: 300,
    title: 'Relativna promjena vrijednosti [%]',
    annotations: {textStyle: {fontName: 'Tahoma', fontSize: 9}},
    vAxis: {textStyle: {fontName: 'Tahoma', fontSize: 9}, format: "#.#'%'",
    viewWindow: {min: data.getColumnRange(4).min-0.5}},
    hAxis: {textStyle: {fontName: 'Tahoma', fontSize: 9}, showTextEvery: 5},
    chartArea: {width: '80%', height: '80%'},
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    colors: ['purple']
  };
  
  var view2 = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view2.setColumns([0,4,{calc:'stringify',sourceColumn:4,type:'string',role:'annotation'}]);

  var container = document.getElementById('Chart2');
  var chart2=new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
    $.each($('text[text-anchor="start"]'), function (index, label) {
      var labelValue = parseFloat($(label).text());
      if (labelValue < 0 && $(label).attr('font-height') !== 'bold') {
        var bounds = label.getBBox();
        var chartLayout = container.getChartLayoutInterface();
        $(label).attr('y',chartLayout.getYLocation(labelValue) - bounds.height - 8);
      }
    });
  });
  observer.observe(container,{childList: true,subtree: true});

  chart2.draw(view2,ColumnOpt);
}
```

```html
<div id="Chart2"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: although bar instead of column, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45243263/5090771) for annotation position -- how are the annotation values added to the table? using a view with `"stringify"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

several issues to deal with here

on this chart, the annotations have attribute --> `text-anchor="middle"`
vs. `text-anchor="start"` on the other

to format the annotations, use a number formatter

```
  var formatAnnotation = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: ColumnOpt.vAxis.format
  });
```

use a custom function on the view, vs. predefined `"stringify"` function

```
var view2 = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view2.setColumns([0,4,{
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    return formatAnnotation.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 4));
  },
  type: 'string',
  role: 'annotation'
}]);
```

this poses a problem with commas in the number
need to replace with decimal for `parseFloat` to handle ok

there is also an issue with annotations overlapping

but this snippet should get you closer...

```js
google.charts.load('current',{callback:drawChart,'packages':['corechart'],'language':'hr'});

function drawChart()
{
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date','Datum');
  data.addColumn('number','Vrijednost');
  data.addColumn('number','Pred. prema preth. 5 dana');
  data.addColumn('number','Pred. prema preth. 10 dana');
  data.addColumn('number','Relativna promjena');
  data.addRows([
  [new Date('2017-08-03'),12.10260,12.09797,12.148753333333,0.3199602122016],
  [new Date('2017-08-02'),12.06400,12.16005,12.176186666667,-0.69882870054079],
  [new Date('2017-08-01'),12.14890,12.12988,12.160606666667,0.3129386508133],
  [new Date('2017-07-31'),12.11100,12.13091,12.14988,-0.001651364026678],
  [new Date('2017-07-28'),12.11120,12.1175,12.116093333333,0.11821210392746],
  [new Date('2017-07-27'),12.09690,12.10942,12.079293333333,0.24113757271416],
  [new Date('2017-07-26'),12.06780,12.10184,12.040733333333,0],
  [new Date('2017-07-25'),12.06780,12.06525,11.992986666667,0.28753781205331],
  [new Date('2017-07-24'),12.03320,12.02595,11.95908,0.18983547592086],
  [new Date('2017-07-21'),12.01040,11.95357,11.932006666667,0.41468798073707],
  [new Date('2017-07-20'),11.96080,11.9183,11.9194,0.1951832460733],
  [new Date('2017-07-19'),11.93750,11.89151,11.914186666667,0.21154604904174],
  [new Date('2017-07-18'),11.91230,11.89439,11.937766666667,0.1235543302851],
  [new Date('2017-07-17'),11.89760,11.93811,11.967046666667,-0.36595680537295],
  [new Date('2017-07-14'),11.94130,11.95136,11.972373333333,0.068716427416171],
  [new Date('2017-07-13'),11.93310,11.96335,11.975713333333,-0.1848567987152],
  [new Date('2017-07-12'),11.95520,11.94968,11.96142,-0.070212979370754],
  [new Date('2017-07-11'),11.96360,11.95871,11.944226666667,0.19429834846403],
  [new Date('2017-07-10'),11.94040,11.9698,11.93224,0.099761076413629],
  [new Date('2017-07-07'),11.92850,11.96977,11.934313333333,-0.13478894228354],
  [new Date('2017-07-06'),11.94460,11.93426,11.931026666667,-0.10036297944233],
  [new Date('2017-07-05'),11.95660,11.86036,11.91198,0.66342251932174],
  [new Date('2017-07-04'),11.87780,11.86771,11.918093333333,0.048011724968622],
  [new Date('2017-07-03'),11.87210,11.88418,11.919446666667,-0.078273604120727],
  [new Date('2017-06-30'),11.88140,11.92094,11.907506666667,-0.076531684958581]
  ]);

  var ColumnOpt = {
    height: 300,
    title: 'Relativna promjena vrijednosti [%]',
    annotations: {alwaysOutside: true, textStyle: {fontName: 'Tahoma', fontSize: 9}, stem: {length: 4, color: 'transparent'}},
    vAxis: {textStyle: {fontName: 'Tahoma', fontSize: 9}, format: "#.#'%'",
    viewWindow: {min: data.getColumnRange(4).min-0.5}},
    hAxis: {textStyle: {fontName: 'Tahoma', fontSize: 9}, showTextEvery: 5},
    chartArea: {width: '80%', height: '80%'},
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    colors: ['purple']
  };

  var formatAnnotation = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: ColumnOpt.vAxis.format
  });

  var view2 = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view2.setColumns([0,4,{
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return formatAnnotation.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 4));
    },
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }]);
  
  var container = document.getElementById('Chart2');
  var chart2=new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
    $.each($('text[text-anchor="middle"]'), function (index, label) {
      var labelValue = parseFloat($(label).text().replace(',', '.'));
      if (labelValue < 0 && $(label).attr('fill') === '#800080') {
        var bounds = label.getBBox();
        var chartLayout = chart2.getChartLayoutInterface();
        $(label).attr('y',chartLayout.getYLocation(labelValue) + bounds.height);
      }
    });
  });
  observer.observe(container,{childList: true,subtree: true});

  chart2.draw(view2,ColumnOpt);
}
```

```html
<div id="Chart2"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: (I often return to my questions/answers and improve them because they are not here for me only). So here, instead of testing bars' purple color with `$(label).attr('fill') === '#800080'` one can specify more precise jquery selector for specific chart `$.each($('div[id="Chart2"] text[text-anchor="middle"]')`. Otherwise this could interfere with other charts. And of course, thanks @WhiteHat for his expertise.