# Visualization: Column Chart - Change annotation position using style: 'line',

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using Visualization: Column Chart and I have the annotations set to 'line', what I want to do is move the position of the annotations so they show above the bar, is this possible?

You can see the issue I am having in the image below:-

[image]

My code is currently as follows:-

```
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
   { calc: "stringify",
     sourceColumn: 1,
     type: "string",
     role: "annotation" },
   2]);                    

var options = {
    title: "{{$sample->name}} {{$test->name}} 'z' scores",
    height: 400,
    annotations: {
        style: 'line',
          textStyle: {
          fontSize: 10,
        },     
    },                         
    bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},                    
    legend: { position: "none" },
    tooltip: {isHtml: true, ignoreBounds: true},             
};
```

If you have a look at the following [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U4VFU/325/), I basically just want to move the annotations directly above the bar, so that they don't obstruct the bar.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: unfortunately, no standard options will change the position of the annotation, when set to `'line'` -- when using `'point'`, you can set `alwaysOutside: true` -- you could move the annotation manually with script, so long as you're not planning to use `getImageURI` to create an image of the chart...

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat - `alwaysOutside: true` doesn't seem to have any effect on the positions, how would you go above moving all annotations manually with script, if I could move all annotations +25px on the 'x' axis and -5px on the 'y' axis that would solve my problem.

Comment: you can use jQuery to modify the charts svg, once it's _ready_ event fires -- I will give an example in a day or two

Comment: the example will be similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43846554/5090771), but still need to figure out how to move the line (`<path>` element) by changing its `'d'` attribute...

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat - just trying to get the negative values to show underneath following your example here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520457/google-chart-negative-positive-values-annotation-position - but can't seem to get this to work